# Inconsistent Avg. Response Times between multiple load test via apache jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I am new to load testing and currently performing load test via apache jmeter 3.3 over LAN. Application being load tested is JAVA and Oracle based.

After each load run that is run for 400 concurrent threads with 400s ramp-up time for 1 hour, we get some avg. response time for each sample/service and tune the required area at either code or server level to reduce avg. response time.

The main problem is that, if multiple load tests are conducted for same time duration with same load on same environment without any change at code/server/network level, there is huge difference in response times when results of these load tests are compared. So, we aren't able to rely on load test results because in some load tests response times for few services is >1s and in next load run it goes beyond 50s. Each load test is conducted in a clean state - application, DB and load test machine is restarted after every load test.

How shall we go about it to conclude actual ART? Should we take an average of average response times obtained in n no. of load tests?

Can anyone please help us figure out the cause for this and any recommendation on this?

Comment: That is too much of a difference. I suspect there is something wrong with the way the test is set up. Some variation is acceptable but 1s and 50s is a way too far to think Jmeter is not correctly collecting the results, there must be something else. I would need more details to help you

Comment: Thanks for the response. Kindly let me know the details required. I can also share the load test results with ART(s)

Comment: The JTL and JMX files. You could remove the server name or IP from your JMX file.